# Execute batch script from .NET (unexpected output)

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a simple batch script from a C# program.

Here's a minimal example:

**Batch file**

```
TIMEOUT /T 30 >nul
EXIT /B 1
```

**C# program**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\xxx.bat";
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        bool exit = process.WaitForExit(120000);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

**Output**

```
"\r\nC:\\Users\\xxx\\bin\\Debug>TIMEOUT /T 30 \r\n\r\nWaiting for 30 seconds, press a key to continue ...\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\xxx\\bin\\Debug>EXIT /B 1 \r\n"
```

I'd expect the batch script to produce no output (due to `nul` redirection of the `timeout` command) but it still does. The output contains the program path and the command text. Why is that? (Is it outputting the script trace eg. like `bash -x`? Google doesn't tell me how/if it could be disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting output to `nul` should only have hidden the output of the redirected command.

Instead, you can add `@echo off` at the start of your bat file.

This will:

> **<sub>[From "Echo", Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772462.aspx)</sub>**
>
> prevent all commands in a batch file (including the echo off
> command) from displaying on the screen.